# CRUD with MVC in win application c#

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

i search a lot google and found many article for CRUD operation with MVC but most of them was for asp.net. i was looking for CRUD operation code in c# with MVC in win application as a result i can see their flow and understand how they are developing their layer in MVC. if anyone know about the url from where i can have sample code for RUD with MVC for win form then please let me know. thanks

Comment: "win application" can still be WinForms or WPF. Instead of posting 4 questions in 10 minutes, please take the time to phrase, format and tag questions properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check 
1. [Rocket Framework](http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/)

Though it is not fully MVC, it is developed with n-tier pattern which  seems good for any enterprise system..

Please talk to the project owner or check the code before making any commitment to use it with high volume enterprise scale systems

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample that I put together of one way to handle CRUD in an ASP.NET MVC application.

http://gpsnerd.codeplex.com/

In this example, the CRUD is handled by a Repository pattern. Let me know if you have any questions.

Bob

Comment: thanks for ur effort but i was looking for CRUD with MVC in win application not asp.net.

Comment: Ah. I see. Not ASP.NET MVC. Sorry.

Comment: Although the CRUD operations (encapsulated by the Repository) are reusable. This type of architecture is meant to be re-used.